Issues with string_size(Message) in Kusto Query Language
Through C# code my application is logging information into kusto.
There is a case when a single message sometimes can have size of more than 200 KB.
So we have implemented below logic to split and log the message in chunks of 10KB, here maxChunkLength is 10000
public static void LogAsChunksToKusto(Dictionary<string, object> data, int maxChunkLength, string tag, string commandName)
    {
        int chunkIndex = 0;
        string input = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += maxChunkLength)
        {
            int length = Math.Min(maxChunkLength, input.Length - i);
            string chunk = input.Substring(i, length);
            chunkIndex++;

            mylogger.GetLogger().LogMessage(EventLevel.Informational, tag, $"Command {commandName} response, part {chunkIndex} : {chunk}", AvNextRequestContext.GetLoggerProperties());
        }
    }

after the change, though the message is being logged in chunk, but the message size is showing 8192  and 7189. It seems it is being logged in chunk of 8 KB, refer below image:

I want to know is there any limitation on kusto logging size?

There is a limit of 8 kb in Azure Application Insights not in the Kusto Query language.

So to summarize:
There is a Field Limit of 8kb per property value. This is causing your string to be truncated.
